# Equality Comparer using generic

Tags: c#, generics, iequalitycomparer

I have a lot of `List` comparison, checked using `sequenceEqual`:

```
this.Details.SequenceEqual<EventDetail>(event.Details, new DetailsEqualityComparer());
```

Since in this way I have a lot of boilerplate, writing tons of class pretty similar (except for the type parameter for `Equals` and `getHashCode`) named `aClassEqualityComparer`, `anotherClassEqualityComparer` and so on...

At this point, i have thinked to rewrite my comparer using generics in this way:

```
class GenericEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.Equals(y);  // here comes the problems
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        // some hashing calculation
    }
}
```

The problem is: as far as I suppose in the `Equals` method, since the used Equals is the Object.Equals and I always get `false`.

Where is the error?

Comment: What do you expect this to do differently from the default equality comparer?

Answer (score 5):

Well, you *could* do:

```
return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);
```

and

```
return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.GetHashCode(x);
```

but that will *still* use reference equality unless `Equals` is overridden for `T` and/or `T` implements `IEquatable<T>` (which may be what you want, but it's not completely clear from your question).

In fact, that implementation would basically replicate `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, so the use of your custom class is redundant - you can just use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` directly without wrapping it.

Comment: If he's already overridden these methods in the base type he doesn't need to create a new `EqualityComparer` that uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, he just needs to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` without a wrapper.

Comment: @Servy Agreed - that's what I mean in the last senetence.  I think you explained it more clearly, though.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to reimplemented default equality comparer that calls instance's `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, which when not implemented by the class will indeed fall back to `Object`'s implementation.

Possibly you want to pass comparer/hash code methods into your comparer:

```
class GenericEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
   Func<T,T,bool> myCompare;
   public GenericEqualityComparer<T>(
      Func<T,T,bool> myCompare, Func<T,int> myGetHashCode)
   {
      this.myCompare= myCompare;                 
       ...
   }

   public bool Equals(T x, T y)
   {
     ....
     return myCompare(T,T);
   }
```